# Можно ли восстановить файлы .java из jar-ника?

Tags: java, jar, декомпиляция

Можно ли восстановить файлы .java из jar-ника ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Да**, это возможно. Есть два способа:

1. Автоматический

   1. Скачиваем [JD-GUI](http://jd.benow.ca/) Java Decompiler (кросплатформенное приложение)
   2. Устанавливаем
   3. Пользуемся

   **НО:** работает оно криво, поэтому на практике придется все равно после него вносить правки.
2. Вручную

   1. Разархивируем файл `*.jar`
   2. Декомпилируем файлы `*.class` (в `IDEA` например)

   **НО:** если классов много - процесс займет *много* времени.

---

Резюмируя вышесказанное, вспомним детскую песенку:

> ***Фарш невозможно провернуть назад и икру обратно в баклажан не вставишь***
>
> ```
> На мотив песни Аллы Пугачевой - Жизнь невозможно повернуть назад
> ```